# Run Cronjob (or equivalent) in Rails 4 App for Continuous/repetitve Tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, cron-task

**TASK**

I want to go through any new records inserted into the database (MySQL) and email them to a personal email address and then mark them as emailed when done. I'd like to do this via a custom written ruby/rails script that is ran via cron (or equivalent).

**Q**

What is the *rails* way (best way) to run a cronjob every night?

Comment: I would go with creating a rake task and scheduling a cron job to run the rake task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) helps you create cron jobs with Rails.